# Flutter: Failed to load dynamic library 'libolm.so' - Library Not Found Error

Tags: android, flutter

I am encountering an issue while working on a Flutter mobile project that involves encryption using libolm. When I attempt to initialize the encryption module in my Flutter code, I receive the following error message:

> Failed to load dynamic library 'libolm.so': dlopen failed: library "libolm.so" not found

I have already ensured that the libolm library is installed on my development machine. But do I need to do any configuration like setting path in my flutter project.

I'm not sure how to resolve it. Has anyone encountered a similar problem with libolm in a Flutter project, and if so, what steps were taken to resolve it?